# difference of lines to file without diff tags

Tags: parsing, unix, indexing, grep, diff

I just want to take the difference of two files and write them to another without patch tags like + or - or diff tags like > or <. I understand how patches work and how to use the following commands:

```
diff file1.txt file2.txt | grep ">" > difffile.txt
diff -u file1.txt file2.txt > difffile.patch
patch original.txt < difffile.patch
```

but when I open my difffile.txt from the first command, I get something like this:

```
> some line of text
> some other line of text
```

when what I reallly want is:

```
some line of text
some other line of text
```

I thought that maybe indexing the string like

```
${stringname:2}
```

would work, but I don't know how to use that with grep or how to index a grep string.

I'm actually parsing html and xml and just want the values differences in some file. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I realize I could do this with a simple c program, but I was wondering if there's a way to do it through a simple command

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove the first two characters of every line, `cut` is your friend:

```
cut -c3- file
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello this is me
and this is you
$ cut -c3- a
llo this is me
d this is you
```